# How to get specific columns from join table using withRelated bookshelf

Tags: bookshelf.js

for example i got 2 tables like;

```
table1 {Id, Name, Description}
table2 {Id, Table1Id, Name, Amount}
```

With bookshelfJS when i using withRelated something like;

```
new table1({Id: 1})
.fetchAll({
    withRelated: ['Childs']})
.then(function(rows) {
    callback(null, rows);
});
```

I expected my result something like;

```
{results: [{Id: '', Name: '', Description: '', Childs: [{Id: '', Name: '', Amount: 123}]}]}
```

I don't want to get **Table1Id** in the Childs list. How can I specify what columns in my output?

**UPDATE**
My models;

```
table1 = bookshelf.Model.extend({
         tableName: 'table1',

         Childs: function() {
            return this.hasMany(table2, 'Table1Id');
         }
});

table2 = bookshelf.Model.extend({
         tableName: 'table2',

         Parent: function() {
            return this.belongsTo(Table1);
         }
});
```

If I'm not select Table1Id

```
new table1({Id: 1})
 .fetchAll({
withRelated: ['Childs':function(qb) {
   qb.select('Id', 'Name', 'Description');
}]})
.then(function(rows) {
      callback(null, rows);
});
```

then return empty for Childs[].
Should be;

```
new table1({Id: 1})
 .fetchAll({
withRelated: ['Childs':function(qb) {
   qb.select('Id', 'Table1Id', 'Name', 'Description');
}]})
.then(function(rows) {
      callback(null, rows);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

well here's the thing: this can be solved pretty easily, but you NEED to select the primary ID of the table in question, otherwise Bookshelf won't know how to tie the data together. The idea is that you get the query builder from the Knex.js and use the `select` method (http://knexjs.org/#Builder-select).

Here's the solution for your case:

```
    new table1({
        Id: 1
    })
    .fetchAll({
        withRelated: [{
            'Childs': function(qb) {
                //always select the primary Id of the table, otherwise there will be no relations between the tables
                qb.select('Id', 'Name', 'Amount'); //Table1Id is omitted!
            }
        }]
    })
    .then(function(rows) {
        callback(null, rows);
    });
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: It's doesn't work if I'm not select parent Id :(. Thanks

Comment: Can you update your question with the new query so i can see what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

in your bookshelf.js file, add the visibility plugin as below

```
bookshelf.plugin('visibility');
```

in your table2 model, hide the unwanted field(s) as below

```
table2 = bookshelf.Model.extend({
         tableName: 'table2',
         hidden: ['Table1Id'],

         Parent: function() {
            return this.belongsTo(Table1);
         }
});
```

you can learn more about the visibility plugin from here
https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Visibility